# Swift3 - Singleton to share UItextfield value not updating second time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am passing UItextfield value using Singelton here is my Singelton class:

```
class CityName {
    static var sharedInstance = CityName()
    private init() {}
    var cityName:String!
}
```

And here is my constant class where I am using this value

```
let WEATHER_URL = BASE_URL + CityName.sharedInstance.cityName + API_Key
```

In my view controller I am using button to pass value:

```
@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    CityName.sharedInstance.cityName = cityNameTextField.text!
    print(CityName.sharedInstance.cityName)
    networkConnection.getWeatherDetails {
        self.currentTempLabel.text = String(self.networkConnection.currentTemp)
        self.minTempLabel.text = String(self.networkConnection.minTemp)
        self.maxtTempLabel.text = String(self.networkConnection.maxTemp)
    }
}
```

and in my network class I am making URL connection

```
func getWeatherDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete)  {
    print(WEATHER_URL)
    Alamofire.request(WEATHER_URL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {                
                if let currentTemperature = main["temp"] as? Double {
                    let kelvinToFarenheitPreDivision = (currentTemperature * (9/5) - 459.67)
                    let kelvinToFarenheit = Double(round(10 * kelvinToFarenheitPreDivision/10))
                    self._currentTemp = kelvinToFarenheit
                    print(self._currentTemp)
                }
            }
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

This code works fine when I enter value in text field first time. But when I add new value in text field my URL is not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the URL anywhere. Change it to mutable by `var WEATHER_URL = BASE_URL + CityName.sharedInstance.cityName + API_Key`, then update in in your `searchButtonTapped()` function.

```
@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    CityName.sharedInstance.cityName = cityNameTextField.text!
    print(CityName.sharedInstance.cityName)
    WEATHER_URL = BASE_URL + CityName.sharedInstance.cityName + API_Key
    networkConnection.getWeatherDetails {
        self.currentTempLabel.text = String(self.networkConnection.currentTemp)
        self.minTempLabel.text = String(self.networkConnection.minTemp)
        self.maxtTempLabel.text = String(self.networkConnection.maxTemp)
    }
}
```

Also, you should use Swift naming convention for each of your variables *(weatherUrl, baseUrl, apiKey)*.